# Web to iOS Handoff not working with subdomains

Tags: ios, ios8, handoff, ios8-handoff

I'm setting up handoff from website to iOS and I'm struggling with the following issue. Website URL has usernames as subdomains: username1.domain.com. On the iOS app's part I have to specify fully qualified domain name in entitlements:

> The native app on the receiving device must opt into this behavior by
>   claiming a domain in the com.apple.developer.associated-domains
>   entitlement. The value of that entitlement has the format
>   'service':'fully qualified domain name', for example,
>   activitycontinuation:example.com.

The problem is that if I specify activitycontinuation:domain.com and user is browsing at username1.domain.com, iOS doesn't recognise this as domain claimed by my app. If I specify username1.domain.com explicitely in entitlements, handoff works only for username1.domain.com. Is there a way to make this work for *.domain.com ?

Comment: First, suggest you ask this on the Apple internal forums - more likely to have someone who knows answer. I just implemented this feature iOS to web, but as I recall the associated domains is an array of domains, not just one - so if you know beforehand which ones you need, you can specify them. There is no wildcard feature (that I know of, or that has been published - but agree it would be a nice feature - writeup a bug report on it)

Comment: @Roman, did you ever get this working for a subdomain?

Comment: @lehn0058 unfortunately, no. We had to move away from subdomains for various other reasons so it was ok for us.